# how to save output from dataframe info to file a excel or text file

Tags: python, pandas, io, buffer, stdout

How can I write

`df.info()` to file?

I would like to include this in a sheet of the excel file where I write my `df` to using `df.to_excel`.

According to the docs ([pandas.DataFrame.info](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)) it returns a

*buf : writable buffer, defaults to sys.stdout*

Comment: I think if you pass a file handle as the param to `buf` then it should write it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
f = open('df.info', 'w+')

df.info(buf=f)

f.close()
```