# pandas df.info() as dataframe to clipboard. How?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df.info()` to a clipboard as a dataframe, so that it can be pasted to Excel for checking on things.

`df.info()` is the only (easy and quick) method that shows ALL the column names of a dataframe whenever the dataframe has LOTS of columns.

What is the best way to get the result into a clipboard for pasting into Excel.. and any other methods.

```
>>> dfcsr2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 19903 entries, 0 to 19902
Data columns (total 88 columns):
seq                  19903 non-null int64
doc_dir              19903 non-null object
carrier              19903 non-null object
flight_number        19903 non-null object
flight_date          19903 non-null datetime64[ns]
sch_arr_time         19903 non-null datetime64[ns]
arr_time             19903 non-null datetime64[ns]
...
...
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save output from dataframe info to file a excel or text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436331/how-to-save-output-from-dataframe-info-to-file-a-excel-or-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a writable buffer if you need to further process the output. I'm writing the buffer value directly to a file. You can write the value to excel too.

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

if you need the column values only just use df.columns i.e. an array value of column and would be more convenient to read and write in excel.

Check Pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)